# How to check for type in Angular template? Object is possibly 'undefined' Property does not exist on type

Tags: angular

I am trying to render data in an Angular template. I want to iterate over it and depending on the type I want to show difference values.

My structure is like this:

```
export interface Bundle {
  resourceType: ResourceType;
  id: string;
  entry?: Entry[];
}
export interface Entry {
  resource?: Bundle | Encounter;
}
```

As you can see, it can be nested. The type Encounter holds different information, but has no "entry" property. So my thought was to just check if it exists:

```
<ng-template *ngIf="entry.resource.entry !== undefined">
  <p-panel
    *ngFor="let resourceEntry of entry.resource?.entry"
    [header]="resourceEntry.resource.id"
  >
...
```

But the compiler throws the error:

> error TS2339: Property 'entry' does not exist on type 'Bundle | Encounter'.
> Property 'entry' does not exist on type 'Encounter'.

Is there any way to check the type in the HTML or any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from the HTML template and not an error somewhere in the .ts file?

Comment: If you could paste your ts file code?

Comment: @Paul that is what the error message says: `Error occurs in the template of component DetailViewComponent.` Also, the error is shown in the templtate in vs code on entry. So I guess it comes from there?

Comment: @user3929590 the Component or the interface definitions? The component only has a constructor which aggregates some information. I had the same issue there and I fixed it with a guard. But that does not work in the template.

Comment: @user3929590 I also subscribe on the service which returns an Observable and save it in the "file" property.

Comment: @user3929590 here you go: https://pastebin.com/1Sns3tzy

Comment: I think won't be possible to check the type in html, you could set variables in ts file based on the data you receive and then have seperate templates for those to render

Comment: @user3929590 okay, thank you. I was thinking about that... Hmm...